# How to link Email/Password sign-in method using Firebase admin SDK?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to use firebase admin SDK in order to link the Email/Password sign-in method.

Based on firebase documentation we can links user to a specific provider https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.updaterequest.md#updaterequestprovidertolink

---

based on that I'm using :

```
await admin
           .auth()
           .updateUser(user.uid, {
                providerToLink: {
                    uid: user.email,
                    email: user.email,
                    displayName: user.displayName,
                    providerId: 'password',
                },
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                console.error(`${error}`);
            });
```

It should link the Email/Password sign-in method to a specific user, but instead of that it's returning error with

- code = `auth/invalid-provider-id`
- message = `The providerId must be a valid supported provider identifier string.`

---

### It's working as expected when the providerId equal to `facebook.com` or `google.com`

**Question**

Is there is another providerId I should use in order to link the Email/Password sign-in method ?

Is there another approach I should use in order to link the Email/Password sign-in method ?

---

Node version : 12

firebase-admin : 9.12.0

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set providerId as 'email' and also provide password.

```
  await admin.auth().updateUser(user.uid, {
    password: "password",
    providerToLink: {
      email: "example@example.com",
      uid: "example@example.com",
      providerId: 'email',
    },
  })
```

Comment: when doing this, I get an error

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_PROVIDER_ID : provider email is not supported for linking.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_PROVIDER_ID : provider email is not supported for linking.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: I guess the "providerId" for email is "password" https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.emailauthprovider#emailauthproviderprovider_id

Answer (score 0):

You can link email and password provider to an anonymous user, updating the user with the admin SDK

```
admin.auth().updateUser("xxxxx", {
  email: "test@test.com",
  password: "abc123"
});
```

After running this code, you will be able to login with that credentials.